# How to avoid naming a variable "varname"?

Tags: python

I am working on a piece of code that contains a variable named `varname`. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, context, taskname, varname='results'):
        self.context = context
        self.taskname = taskname
        self.varname = varname

    def execute(self):
        """
        Dispatch this task to the correct handler.

        """
        logger.info(f"Running task: {self.taskname}")
        try:
            handler = getattr(self, self.taskname)
        except AttributeError:
            raise RuntimeError(f'Task "{self.taskname}" is currently not implemented')

        # Assign output of task to ``varname``
        context[self.varname] = handler()
        return context
```

The `Task` class is intended to be used by a task runner where callers can specify the name of the task and also a "varname" where the results will be stored. That way, subsequent tasks can refer to the results of earlier tasks. Multiple tasks are run like this:

```
execution_context = {}
todolist = [
    ('some_task', 'results'),
    ('some_other_task', None),
]
for task_name, varname in todolist:
   task = Task(execution_context, task_name, varname)
   execution_context.update(task.execute())
```

Here is my question: How can I avoid using a variable named `varname` in this situation? It seems silly to have a variable *that holds the name of* another variable (well, actually the name of a dictionary key). Of course, I can rename the variable, but in the past when I've been confronted with situations like this, there was usually a more elegant solution than "evaluating" variable names. Or is there perhaps nothing wrong with this approach?

Comment: You can't really have *variable variables* at all (\* only in limited situations is it technically possible at all). As you say, it's really the key of a dict. So… name it "job id" or whatever is use it as the key in a "job results" dict…?

Comment: Sure you can: `x = eval(varname)` :)

Comment: Yeah, but I’d never consider that a real option. There is basically never a reason to do that vs. `x = d[varname]`.

Comment: Besides renaming `varname`, is there another way to refactor this code?

Comment: Yeah, I’m not sure what problem you’re really trying to solve, other than that “varname” doesn’t really express what this does.